# File VERSION or include/CGAL/version.h are missing, required by release-build

Tags: linux, fedora, cgal

I'm trying to compile CGAL libraries on fedora 27 
but when I compile them using cmake ,it show's the following message:

```
CMake Error: Unable to open check cache file for write. /home/xx/Documents/CGAL-4.11/build/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:22 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0042 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.11
Packagenames: CGAL-4.11
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:275 (message):
  File VERSION or include/CGAL/version.h are missing, required by
  release-build.
```

any help ,please ?

Comment: This may be more on topic on [SO], since it's probably more to do with cmake or your compiler toolchain than CGAL itself. In any case: where did you get the sources? (git, source rpm, etc.) And, how did  you run/configure cmake?

Comment: I downlaod cgal package from the official site ,and other prerequisites libs (eg:boost,gmp,..) from dnf package manager